# Android - Push Notification sound and open activities issues

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

This is a two part issue. I have push notifications work with my app but I can't get a custom sound to work, 1. 2. I can't get the notifications to open the app when you click on it from the notification bar.

This is the code below. I've tried various things to import a custom sound. The sound in in my assets/sounds folder. Will that be carried over with the apk when installed and how to I access it? I'm using webview as well like to open the app to a specific link from the notification, can that be done also?

```
private void sendGCMIntent(final Context theContext, String theMessage) 
    {   
    int icon = R.drawable.noti_icon;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                theContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, theMessage, when);

        String title = theContext.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(theContext, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(theContext, title, theMessage, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        //String path = "file:///android_asset/sounds/soft.mp3"; 

        //File file = new File(path);

        //Log.i(TAG,"Sound exists : " + file.exists());
        Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/sounds/soft.mp3");

        if (soundUri != null) {
            notification.sound = soundUri;
        }
        else {
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        }
        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);    
    }
```